# 2 last rows in same Range

Tags: excel, vba

Im having a little problem, I would like to fill the cells between A +lastrow1 and And A+lastrow2 with "10"....

I tried like this but it gave me "run time error 5  Invalid procedure call or argument"

Can you help me out?

> ```
> lastRow1 = wbk.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
> lastRow2 = wbk.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
>
> wbk.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & lastRow1 : "A" & lastRow2).Value = "10"
> ```

Comment: Change `: "A"` to `& ":A"`

Comment: more precisely: `wbk.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & lastRow1 & ":A" & lastRow2).Value = "10"`

Comment: It worked, thanks!

Comment: As a side note, do no use such notation as youd - better, use `Cells`: `With wbk.Sheets("Sheet1"): .Range(.Cells(lastRow1, "A"), .Cells(lastRow2, "A").Value = "10": End With`